# Understanding UDFs in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

**Introduction**

I created a **UDF** in a **module** in Access that looks like this:

```
Public Type Postings

PostingID As Long
CompanyID As Variant
NetAmt    As Double
VATAmt    As Double

End Type
```

This is how I use it:

```
Dim P as Postings
'set variables 
P.PostingID = 1
P.CompanyID = ABC123
P.NetAmt    = 100
P.VATAmt    = 20
.
.
'Do Save proc
```

**Problem**

When I have to save multiple entries of the above, the variables do not reset to "nothing" even when I run a reset function to set them to nothing again.

Therefore if I am entering 2 lines of data for example - this is what is looks like:

```
PostingID      CompanyID       NetAmt      VATAmt
    1           ABC123          100          20
    2           BCD123          200          20
```

The second line is **WITHOUT VAT** - however since I assigned **P.VATamt** as **20** in the first one it has sustained the Variable as 20 for the second posting.

I even have a reset variable function which sets everything to nothing before it does anything each time it loops.
So I do not understand why I am still getting the variable carried through.

Any Suggestions on how to use UDFs best and reset the variables they hold?

Comment: I do that in a function which assigns everything to 0 or null etc but i dont understand why it doesnt work...

Comment: Is it just me of have you made a UDT instead of a UDF?

Comment: just noticed that you're right

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue:

In my function I had used a separate Dim to the main procedure. Therefore it was not linking.

I passed the Dim P postings into the function that clears everything and it works.

PS. Its  UDT not UDF that I created.